# Heading and paragraph overlap

Tags: html, css

I'll try to keep this simple. But I'm literally making my first site with HTML, css and javascript. And I can't find a definitive answer how to stop text overlapping in some situations. Ex. i had a paragraph and wanted to put a heading below it but because of my bad positioning they overlap. Heres the css code for both. Also is it okay to use percentages like I did in paragraph?

```
h2{
color : #D50505;
text-align : left;
font-family: Government Agent;
font-size: 40px;
}

.paragraph1 {

color : #F5C438;
text-align: center;
font-family: Government Agent;
font-size: 20px;
position : absolute;
top : 20%;
}
```

Comment: I would solve this by simply putting 
    h2{
    position: absolute;
    top: x px;
    }
so the heading would be below text. It that a good solution?

Comment: add the html code

Answer (score 0):

It is not much helpful in responsive design.
I prefer to use "vw" i.e. "viewport width" or "vh" i.e. "viewport height".

Answer (score 0):

It really does depend on where you're using it. It looks to me like you're trying to place your paragraph of text somewhere on your screen. Note that if you use pixels, if you change the size of the screen or window, the paragraph may no longer be in the correct place if you use pixels. You should look into responsive web design. Percentages are a pretty good place to start understanding that concept.

Answer (score 0):

Percentages are calculated on monitor size, 10% will cover 10% of a monitor screen
10px will show 10 pixels on a small screen and large screen,

I suggest using VH or VW, furthermore width use for percentages and height do pixels

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when you use it, it may be good or bad. If you use it to scale an item along the x-axis (specify the width of an element), you may end up with a constant width throughout all devices, which isn't the best for responsive web design (RWD). But, if you are trying to specify a margin or padding (best use in margin-top|margin-bottom or padding-top|padding-bottom), then it may be fine, as long as it is for **vertical** scaling. You can learn more about RWD [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp).